# page refresh before ajax success response how can get the response after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

is there any way to send an ajax request but before the ajax success response? I reload my browser page. and still, how I will be able to get the response

Comment: You can only get the response on the same page. After reloading it will not be available anymore. Add the code to your question when you ask a question in the future.

Comment: And I wonder, if you need to reload the page, why are you using AJAX?

Comment: Also why do you need to reload the page? Sounds like you ran into an issue which you hoped to solve with reloading the page.

Comment: I don't need to reload the page after ajax request. but there are many chances the client may reload the page before getting an ajax response.

Comment: @azhar everything is simple.  Response for ajax requets goes back directly to its initiator. If your client will reload page till ajax request get response it means that you will loose ajax response and should request it once again from new page if needed.

Comment: thanks for your response.
is there any best solution to prevent this issue?